# How to render array of object?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
const jsx = []
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) { 
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row row' + (i + 1);
    row.id = 'row' + (i + 1);
    for (var j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
        var node = document.createElement('div');
        node.className = 'node node' + ((i * 10) * (j + 1));
        node.id = 'node' + count;
        count++;
        row.appendChild(node);
    }
    jsx.push(row);
}    
  

return (
    <div className='maze'>
       {jsx}
    </div>
)
```

```
Error Cannot render  object use array instead
```

this code is running in javascript

Basically, I want 25 divs, and in each div 25 div children. Can you suggest react approach to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the React tutorial? You'll figure out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you can just "describe" the HTML you want, i.e. `<div>....</div>`. There's no need really to create elements, that's what React does.

You could generate 2 arrays, each of length you need, and map them to the JSX you want.

Example 10x10:

```js
const App = () => [...Array(10).keys()].map(row => (
  <div key={row}>
    (row {row})[
    {[...Array(10).keys()].map(col => (
      <span key={col}>[{col}]</span>
    ))}
    ]
  </div>
));

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this

```
<div className=''>
        {new Array(25).fill(0).map(div => {
          <div className="">
            {new Array(25).fill(0).map(innerDiv => {
              <div className=""></div>
            })}
          </div>
        })}
        </div>
```